# v-for with conditional element, without <!-- -->

Tags: vue.js, nodes, audit, v-for, lighthouse

I can't find the answer to my question in other questions so decided to post my own.

First of, I know you should filter an array before looping through it. But in my case it's not the array itself that's giving me my troubles.

In my case I am looping through an array with products. This renders my  component. Now every xx products I want to render a promotion text which is in between the product-components.

So my code:

```
<template v-for="(product, index) in products">
<product>
<promotion v-if="showOnIndex(index)">
</template>
```

Now my question is, is this the way to go?

When the code renders it inputs `<!-- -->` after every product, does this affect the number of nodes Google counts when doing an Audit?

Is there a way to prevent the empty comment tag?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the behaviour of a false condition under `v-if`. You can also check this [thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5117) for the reason.

If you use `v-show` you'll remove the empty tags, but will have promotion nodes for all products.

One way of fixing this is to have 2 components for products:

- product
- productWithPromotion

and use [:is](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to switch between them

```
<template v-for="(product, index) in products">
 <component :is="showOnIndex(index)? 'product' : 'productWithPromotion'" />
</template>
```